# Communicating computer to computer over internet

Tags: objective-c

Is there a sample app out there that has communication between 2 computers? For example:

Both computers have an objective-c app, both send messages back and forth. And both computers are in different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit underspecified -- there are many ways for two Objective-C applications to communicate over a network -- but assuming that you are okay with Cocoa, here is an article which walks through (with code) the construction of a chat server/client which communicates over Unix sockets: http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2003/05/13/cocoa.html